# Slick 3.2: Filtering on columns from left-joined table

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0, typesafe

Given the following using Slick 3.2:

```
val contacts = TableQuery[ContactTable]
val phones = TableQuery[PhoneTable]

val query = contacts.joinLeft(phones).on(_.contact_id === _.id)

query.filter{ case (contact, maybePhone) => ... }
```

maybePhone is a Rep[Option[PhoneTable]].  How can I filter on its properties?  (Something like maybePhone.contains(_.areaCode === "212").)

Comment: If you want to filter by the value of the column of the joined table, why do you use `leftJoin` (instead of inner join) in the first place?

Comment: Good question.  I'm defining a generic base query that an API exposes for reuse.  Some callers will not care about the left joined table or its values.  Others will sometimes want to filter on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try mapping:

```
query.filter{ case (contact, maybePhone) => maybePhone.map(_.areaCode === "212") }
```

Comment: That works!  I don't know how I missed that.  (Never code while sleep-deprived I suppose.)  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to pattern match it and got a nasty type-error. Not it works!